# How to solve "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED" using mailchimp API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, mailchimp

I'm trying to connect to the API mailchimp by using this code:

```
const client = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');

client.setConfig({
  apiKey: "MY API KEY",
  server: "MY SERVER",
});

async function run() {
  const response = await client.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}

run();
```

In my code, I have the real API KEY and SERVER but I put fake one in here.

After I run my main.js, I have this error that come and I don't know how to solve it:

```
(node:28092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 72.9.105.30:443
(node:28092) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have already install mailchimp by using:

```
npm install mailchimp
```

But the error still come.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing
```

check [mailchimp_marketing documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing)

```
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing');
 
mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  server: 'YOUR_SERVER_PREFIX',
});
 
async function callPing() {
  const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}
 
callPing();
```

Comment: Yes, I've already try with @mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing but the same error come.